# Turning a single value into an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

In my project I often find myself checking if a value is an array.

If the value is not an array I create a single element array from it.

If the value is `undefined` or `null`, I create an empty array.

The value itself is usually either an array of objects or a single object or `undefined`

```
const array = value ? (Array.isArray(value) ? value: [value]) : [];
```

Is there a more succinct way of doing this (perhaps with `lodash` or `underscore`), before I decide to factor this into a separate util function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do

```
var eventsArray = events ? [].concat(events) : [];
```

The `.concat()` function accepts both arrays and individual arguments, so either way you end up with what you want.

Answer (score 5):

since you are using const in your code I assume you are using ES2015 / ES6. ES1015's 
[Default function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed.

```
function abc(value = []) {

  const array =  Array.isArray(value) ? value: [value];

}
```

Comment: if you pass undefined or null, value parameter is set to empty array

Comment: @RolandStarke In my case I would want [], not [null]

Comment: @Darshan null will result in [null]

Answer (score 2):

### A condensed ES2020 way to ensure a variable is an array:

```
value = [].concat(value ?? [])
```

#### Explanation

As @VoteyDisciple explained, the [concat function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) will concatenate single values or an arrays of values. The [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) will use the value on the right (the second empty array) if the value on the left is null or undefined. So if value is null, it will concatenate an empty array to an empty array, which returns an empty array.

#### Examples

```
// Different inputs and outputs
values = [].concat([1,2,3] ?? [])   // [1,2,3]
values = [].concat(1 ?? [])         // [1]
values = [].concat(null ?? [])      // []

// Wrap it in a function if you like
function array(value) {
    return [].concat(value ?? [])
}

// Use it like this
values = array(values)

// Or even like this
for (let value of array(values)) {
    console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple, plus works with an object as a value. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you ALWAYS end up concatting an array.  And for large arrays in a loop it will end up VERY expensive.  Speaking from experience.

Comment: @krl You always end up concatting an array, but if you're concatting a large array (or any value at all), then this is identical to the accepted answer. The only difference in performance is when the value you pass to this is null or an empty array. In that situation, instead of just assigning an empty array, you concat an empty array to an empty array and then assign it.

Having said that, you are correct in that even concatting an empty array to an empty array is not zero cost and the difference in the amount of code you type is negligible, so I'd say just go with the accepted answer.

Comment: @dallin What I meant to say is that in my question, if the value is an array, we just use it as is.  Running time O(1).  In your example, you always end up copying an array with running time O(n).  In a loop, this just kills performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using lodash's [**castArray**](https://lodash.com/docs#castArray) and [**isNil**](https://lodash.com/docs#isNil) all wrapped up in a [**mixin**](https://lodash.com/docs#mixin):

```
_.mixin( {'asArray' : function(value){
    return _.isNil(value) ? [] : _.castArray(value);
}});
```

Usage:

```
_.asArray(null)      -> []
_.asArray(undefined) -> []
_.asArray(0)         -> [0]
_.asArray(false)     -> [false]
_.asArray([1,2,3])   -> [1,2,3]
_.asArray('wibble')  -> ['wibble']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use ES6, you can do the following, it's cleaner than `.concat()`;

```
function method(value = []) {
  const array = [...value];
}
```

Comment: If value is non-iterable, this won't work, but OP asked for solution where he can have any type of value transformed into an array. So `.concat()` is the way to go.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you ALWAYS end up interating through an array. For large arrays in some external loops it will end up VERY expensive.

Answer (score 1):

## Even shorter solution using `.flat()`

There is an even slicker way to do it if you don't have to check for the `undefined` or `null` value. This basically converts the value to a singleton array if it was not an array before.

```js
[value].flat()
```

### Example usage

```js
[12].flat() // Output: [12]
[[[12]]].flat() // Output: [[12]]
```

### Removing nullish values

If you want to remove nullish values - just add a filter on top of that. This will remove all the values that are falsy.

```js
[value].filter(x => x).flat()
```

#### Pitfalls

Due to the fact that `0` (and `false`) is a falsy value, if you are storing numbers in an array it is advised to explicitly compare array values with `null` or `undefined`.

```js
[value].filter(x => x !== null && x !== undefined).flat()
```

In order to shorten it a bit we could use Lodash's [isNil](https://lodash.com/docs#isNil) method.

```js
[value].filter(_.isNil).flat()
```

Comment: I need to check for null and undefined.  Also if the value is already an array, you'll have both `flat` and `filter` going through the whole array on each check, which can easily become a performance issue if used in a loop.

Comment: Oh... sorry I forgot to flip the order of the `flat` and `filter`. This may look expensive... however we only iterate over a singleton array. This solution is O(1) time complexity. If you are not using this snippet in an extremely performent code section - it should be good enough.

Comment: We had big performance issues with arrays and hot code segments, so we always prefer a version that doesn't have even potential issues.  Because the code that's not hot now, may become hot some time later.  As I said the problem is that if you already get an array as input, both `filter` and `flat` will iterate over the whole array causing `O(n)`.  And if the array is huge (we have those) and the check is performed in a loop, you're in trouble. Our default solution is not succinct but it's always `O(1)`.

Comment: Well then if you write critical code then sure, as per my last message - use something else. I'm not sure what are you trying to convey. The fact that filter iterates over an array is correct, it's time complexity is indeed `O(n)` where `n` is the length of array in which case is `1` thus `O(1)`. So we do one item filter and one element unwraping. There is something worse than what you didn't see - we create 2 additional arrays - the filtered one and the flatten one. But again... back to what I said. This is not an ideal code for critical code usage - it's a nice short alternative.

Comment: As I said we avoid using code that can cause performance issues because in a big code base it will be extremely hard to find and fix.  So by looking for a more succinct alternative, we implicitly look for something that also has `O(1)`.