# Turning single values and arrays into arrays including zeros as single value

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

While I was searching for a good way to check if a function variable is an array or a single variable and then turn both into arrays for further processing, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943735/turning-a-single-value-into-an-array/35943967#35943967).

The answer provided by @VoteyDisciple

```
var eventsArray = events ? [].concat(events) : [];
```

works great for me until `events` is a single variable with a value of zero. In that case, `eventsArray` will be empty. Here is my entire code:

```
var eventsArray = [];
if (!(Array.isArray(events))) {
  eventsArray = events ? [].concat(events) : [];
} else {
  eventsArray = events;
}
```

I have tried to make another if-statement before the `else` line to catch this special occasion. But that ends up in a mess for the rest of the code and I doubt it's very elegant. Therefore I wonder if it is possible to change this line:

```
eventsArray = events ? [].concat(events) : [];
```

in a way so that if `events` is a single variable with a value of zero, this line will also turn this occasion into an array with a single element and a value of zero?

For understanding things better, I also want to ask: Why does this line of code "lose" the zero but works great with any other single value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler:

```
eventsArray = Array.isArray(events) ? events : [events];
```

The reason you lose the zero is because zero is falsey in a boolean context like the conditional operator. You'll also lose `null` and empty strings.